# Typescript does not detect illegal argument

Tags: typescript

Typescript does not detect any error in the code below.

```
interface testIF {
    test(): void;
    test2(map: Map<string, number>): void
}

function f(): testIF {

    return {
        test: function () {
            let map: Map<string, string> = new Map();
            this.test2(map);                          // Passing Map<string, string>
        },

        test2: function(map: Map<string, number>) {

        }
    }    
}
```

The argument of `test2` must be `Map<string, **number**>` and the function `test` passes `Map<string, **string**>` to `test2`. The argument type does not match, but Typescript does not detect this error.

Why Typescript does not detect this error?

Typescript version: 2.9.2.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2017",
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": [
    :
  ],
  "exclude":  [
    :
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try turning on the `noImplicitThis` compiler option in tsconfig. I believe without that (Can't explain why - probably a bug) `this` is being implicitly typed as `any` when using the factory function syntax

Comment: Thanks for comment. Setting `noImplicitThis` to `true` could detect the error. Could you make an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: If you set that flag, does the type of `this` change? (Do you still get an error even if you use the method correctly?)

Comment: After setting `noImplicitThis`, the above code generates the error `TS2345: Argument of type 'Map<string, string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Map<string, number>'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.`. It looks the type of `this` is `testIF`.

Comment: That's cool! I didn't know that `noImplicitThis` causes the compiler to interpret `this` as the object's type. I thought it just caused the compiler to error out if `this` was interpreted as `any`.

Comment: N.F Looks like @FrankModica 's answer is more prescribed way to deal with this. [Here is some info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PSL advice, I have set `noImplicitThis` to `true` on `tsconfig.json`. Now Typescript can detect the error.

Answer (score 2):

The way you invoke the method can change the value of `this`, so TypeScript sets `this` to be of type `any` by default, which turns off type checking. You can tell TypeScript the context by creating a fake parameter called a `this` parameter:

```
function f(): testIF {

    return {
        test: function (this: testIF /* fake "this" parameter */) {
            let map: Map<string, string> = new Map();
            this.test2(map); // Error
        },

        test2: function(map: Map<string, number>) {

        }
    }    
}
```